# While starting Hive I am getting SSL error. Its working but I cant perform bucketing until I resolve the error

Tags: mysql, hadoop, ssl, hive, mysql-connector

Below is the error:

```
Tue Sep 12 03:21:00 IST 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without 
server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 
5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be 
established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance 
with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate 
property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL 
by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for 
server certificate verification.
```

How can I resolve this issue.Any Idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is SSL warning it can be fixed by putting **"?useSSL=false"** in Jdbc connection string Present at hive-site.xml.

ie

```
  <property>

  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>

  <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore?useSSL=false</value>

  <description>metadata is stored in a MySQL server</description>
```

Comment: Accepted.I am new here So I don't know a lot about stackoverflow. still need 4 more points to upvote.And thanks again for your help.